# XmlSerializer.Deserialize() is too slow with files over 1MB - .Net compact framework 3.5 sp1

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I got a XML schema for which I used xsd.exe to generate a Class `FooClass`.

I am receiving xml requests from host which I get them from a directory and use the `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` to get a Instance of my `FooClass`.

Well, this worked till now perfectly and it still does, but suddenly I started to get XML files which are larger (about 300KB) and the time which it takes to `Deserialize()` is not acceptable! Loading the same XML file with `XMLTextReader()` takes milliseconds and the time to deserialize is about 1 minute and 30 seconds!

So I thought I'll use the XMLReader to read the XML file and build `FooClass` by myself!
But before I start to rework all my code, I would like to ask you if there is a way to use `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` which would be faster?

I am not sure if XMLSerializer Assembly would help me much here?

here is my code which will be called in a Loop for each file

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmldata)
{
   XmlSerializer sz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooClass));
   foo = (FooClass)sz.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
AK

Comment: Are you sure it's the XML and not for example schema resolver timeout?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but yes I am sure! since there are no external schemas/namespaces defined! XML files which are small like 100KB, can be Deserialize fast enough to close an eye LOL. So if resolving would be a problem, must be for all sized XML files! I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new `DataContractSerializer` in .NET 3.5?  The way you use it is pretty much the same as `XmlSerializer`; whether it's any faster I don't know, but it has many other benefits over the `XmlSerializer` such as serialising private members, not needing a parameterless constructor, being able to ignore properties etc.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmldata))
{
    DataContractSerializer s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FooClass));
    FooClass c = s.ReadObject(ms) as FooClass;
}
```

You will need to add the `[DataContract]` attribute to `FooClass`'s definition, and you don't have to, but I explicitly tell the serialiser which members I want serialising by decorating them with `[DataMember]`.

```
[DataContract]
public class FooClass
{
    public string IgnoreThisProperty { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string SerialiseThisProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I haven't used the DataContractSerializer yet, but I'll try it if I don't find any other way! ;-)
The problem is to redesign/Decorate the FooClass! Is there any toold like the xsd.exe which will generate a Class supporting the DataContractSerializer?

Comment: If you need to conform to a specific XML schema, DataContractSerializer won't really help you, because it gives you much less control the document structure

Comment: @Thomas - I agree the DataContractSerializer doesn't allow as much control over the XML, but in a previous comment it doesn't look the poster is using any schemas, so it may be enough. @Gohlool, there's no need to redesign your class, just put [DataContract] above the class definition, and [DataMember] above each property you want to be (de-)serialised.  Converting a class from XmlSerializer to DataContractSerializer takes seconds, depending on its complexity and relationships with other classes.